# HTMX Websockets are not replacing content in DOM

Tags: websocket, htmx

I am trying to get an HTMX Websocket to work. It is a Chat system and should replace the chat content via websocket.

This is the Code snippet of the chat:

```
<div class="min-h-96">
    <div hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/socket/register-chat/{{.ChatId}}">
    </div>
    <div id="chat-messages"></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <form class="flex w-full" hx-post="/actions/message" hx-target="#chat-messages" id="chat-form">
        <input type="text" name="chatId" value="{{.ChatId}}" hidden>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht..." name="message"
            class="w-4/5 p-2 border rounded-l-md border-blue-300 focus:outline-none" autofocus>
        <button type="submit"
            class="w-1/5 bg-blue-600 text-white py-2 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none">Absenden</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The connection is established
[image]

And content is received
[image]

But for some reason I cannot grasp it will not replace it in the DOM. Neither directly into the div that contains the websocket data, neither into the div with the id "chat-messages" when there is an `hx-target` command....

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Could be that you're missing "ws-send" attribute in your form tag? And I think looking at the docs the form should be enclosed inside ws-connect div to get it to work..

Comment: I am using the socket only to receive. The send is an hx-post (which will in the future just post the form data without swapping anything once this is fixed)

Answer (score 0):

So, i found the solution thanks to [this post](https://www.softwarefactory-project.io/introduction-to-htmx-through-a-simple-web-chat-application.html) (that uses Haskell...)

The content that comes back from the Server NEEDS THE SAME ID.

So the currently working setup is as follows.

This snippet creates the websocket connection

```
<div class="min-h-96">
    <div hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/socket/register-chat/{{.ChatId}}" hx-target="chat-messages">
    </div>
    <div id="chat-messages"></div>
</div>
```

The messages need to be wrapped in a div with the same id of the target.

```
<div id="chat-messages">
    {{range .Messages}}
    <div class="flex mb-4 {{if .IsKunde}} justify-end {{end}}" id="{{.MessageId}}">
        <div class="message-container max-h-screen overflow-y-auto max-w-[50%]">
            <div class="text-gray-600">
                <p>{{.SentFrom}}</p>
                <p class="text-xs text-blue-500">{{.SentAt}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rounded-lg {{if .IsKunde}} bg-blue-600 {{else}} bg-lime-700 {{end}} text-white py-2 px-4">
                {{.Message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{end}}
</div>
```

How intuitive and well documented *smh*